# Character Escape in HTML

Tags: html, escaping

Often in coding languages, there is an escape character which either

1. makes the next character interpreted literally or
2. makes the next character interpreted as code within a string.

Is there such an escape character in HTML, or do I need Javascript to do so?
Searching both the internet and stackoverflow yielded no results.

Comment: HTML does not use the concept of an escape character but has a [numeric character reference NCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) which is perhaps what you mention with 2. in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you're talking about is the difference from including something like "<" as a part of a tag such as `<div>` and as just a string to symbolize 'less than'.  That is, the escape for "<" would be `&lt;`.  If so, you can find a full list of escapes [here](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php?PHPSESSID=8cbbddde9a9c9825467546f1c98fe119).  No JavaScript is required.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, all escape characters begin with `&#` and end with `;`, however the actual escape character varies depending on what you're writing. Here are some references for you:

Further explanation: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes

List of escape characters: http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php?PHPSESSID=8cbbddde9a9c9825467546f1c98fe119